Invalid Request : Keycloak with NET MAUI
I am trying an authentication with keycloak. I am using the Web Authenticator. But when browser tries to authenticate, it says "Invalid Request".
Here are some files.
WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity.cs
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
              DataHost = "auth",
              DataScheme = CALLBACK_SCHEME)]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Microsoft.Maui.Authentication.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{
    const string CALLBACK_SCHEME = "myapp";
}

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

Login Method ( It is using Web Authenticator )
private async Task Login()
   {
       try
       {
           var result = await authenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new WebAuthenticatorOptions
           {
               CallbackUrl = new Uri("myapp://auth"),
               Url = new Uri("https://server-url/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/auth")
           });
           var res = result.AccessToken;

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

       }
   }

Valid redirect URIs

Please tell me if I am making any mistake in configuration.
Browser should ask for username and password for signing in to keycloak.

Can you make sure the Uri("https://server-url/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/auth") work? Did you try to open it in the browser directly?
